# How to secure all my passwords with Kee Pass 2 or something else?

Tags: password-management, client-side

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to securely store my passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/how-to-securely-store-my-passwords)

I have a lot of passwords to lots of logins across websites, SSH logins, e-mails and what not.
Is there one program that can secure this all for me, maybe reside on a USB Key and can automatically enter my password when its needed? So i just have to plugin the USB Key?

I'm trying out Kee Pass but not sure how its supposed to work.

Comment: Hi @kzap, welcome to the site! Please take a few minutes to look around the site, if you use the search function I'm sure you'll find lots more relevant and interesting questions.